# Accessing to animationDuration and animationRepeatCount in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder

I'd like to set the animationDuration and animationRepeatCount properties of UIImageView directly in interface builder but I don't see those properties.

Is there a way to choose the properties that are displayed in interface builder ?
(Note that I'm using XCode 4)

I want to do this because I have one ViewController that can handle many XIB files so I can't set those properties in the code of the viewController. Moreover each XIB file contains many UIImageView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of my knowledge it is impossible to set *animationDuration* and *animationRepeatCount* properties of *UIImageView* in XIB. I hope that you are setting the ***animationImages*** in code. Just, set the above two properties in code while you set the *animationImages.*

Comment: This won't work for me : the images are in a directory that has the same name as the imageView Tag, so I'm able to load the correct images just by looking at the image view tag. For the animationDuration, it is dependant of many things so all imageView have a different animation duration and repeat count. I could build files to store those data, but it would be easier for me to get the info directly from the XIB.